# Twitter4j Login Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

When I login with username and password i get this error : 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
message - Sorry, that page does not exist.
code - 34

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new
                ConfigurationBuilder();
                configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey("***");
                configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("***");

                Configuration configuration = (Configuration)configurationBuilder.build();

                        AccessToken accessToken=null;
                        Twitter twitter=null;
                        boolean Login=false;
                        while(!Login)
                        {try{
                        accessToken = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance().getOAuthAccessToken(ScreenName,
                        Password);
                        Login=true;
                        }catch(TwitterException e1 )
                        {

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
                            System.out.println(ScreenName+e.toString());
                            if(e1.getMessage().contains("were missing or incorrect"))
                                {
                                Login=false;
                                break;
                                }


                        }
                        }
                        twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance(accessToken);
```